# How to vagrant up ( with puphpet ) on windows 7 x64 with vagrant 1.7.2?

Tags: ruby, ssl-certificate, vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

I'm new to vagrant, but I have tried it once a several months ago.

Now it just don't get to work, I have generated the puphpet config and downloaded - of course ruby and the puppet gem and virtualbox has been installed - but when I hit vagrant up it pushes error about certificates and so on:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to fin
 install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/trusty64"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I have installed the mozilla CA bundle certificates and added the system variable 'SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH' and the path is working - This was a solution for the gem package manager problem.

Anyone has an Idea how to figure this out?

Thanks in Advance,
Danny

**System I'm trying to work on:** *(Win7 x64, Ruby 2.1.5p, Vagrant 1.7.2, git installed)*

---

#### Solved

The certification problem was a fault of AVG Antivirus on the system, the cURL could not look up because of AVG Firewall.
I have switched off avg for a while and downloaded the boxes... after - with avg running again - I could start up boxes with the previously downloaded boxes.

Comment: Solved by temporarily disabling AVG here too. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Hope this answer helps someone like me in the same situation. Was getting the same SSL error when downloading ubuntu box.
I've opened the file "Vagrantfile" with notepad and added the following line right before end:

**config.vm.box_download_insecure = true**

Found this flag in [Vagrant's documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned creating this via puphpet, but seeing `hashicorp/trusty64` means you're changing things around in the `Vagrantfile`.

Please note that while puphpet's configs *should* work on other boxes that are not `puphpet/*`, I can't and won't provide "official" support for them. Puphpet's also new and small enough that not that many people on SO are able to provide in-depth answers to problems.

Comment: True, this log was just the last of my attempts to get this thing work. After I have disabled AVG it was works, so as I have wrote on the update section that was my solution on this os with this config of vagrant, antivirus ... etc. :) btw thanks for notice.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had the same issue. Do we have a better workaround, maybe in AVG settings, to stop needing to desactivate AVG while installing a box ?

Comment: Got it : Just turn AVG in "interactive mode" and you will be asked for outgoing connexions and autorisations. So vboxheadless.exe can pass trough the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to disable antivirus software during installation of vagrant package.
Looks like antivirus programs like to silently remove CA certificates bundle during installation.

Comment: I think its not. All of previously used certificates stored at is place and has not disabled or removed. As I have teset this out, only the cURL of windows has been blocked by AVG. I have added it to the excluded / enabled applications and it works.